# Wrapping carousel indeces

Tags: javascript

I made a simple wrapping carousel but I'm having issues if global index get's into negative numbers.

```js
// relevant parts
const middle = index % (slides.length - 0);

function getLeftRight (middle) {
    return {
    left: (middle - 1 + slides.length) % slides.length,
    right: (middle + 1) % slides.length,
  };
}
```

How to get it to work with negative numbers as well?

Sorry about the amount of CSS and fluff here, I wanted to drive my point home. You can ignore CSS and HTML.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rs6gntvc/)

```js
// 5 slides
const slides = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

const slidesEl = document.getElementById('slides');
// populate slides[] with slides elements
for (let i = 0; i < slidesEl.children.length; i++) {
  slides[i] = slidesEl.children[i].children[0];
}

// global index
let index = 2;
// previous middle index, helps
// to clean up previous styles
let prevMiddle = index;

function getLeftRight(middle) {
  return {
    left: (middle - 1 + slides.length) % slides.length,
    right: (middle + 1) % slides.length,
  };
}

// set up initial active classes
const leftRight = getLeftRight(index);
slides[index].classList.add('middle');
slides[leftRight.left].classList.add('left');
slides[leftRight.right].classList.add('right');

function update(direction) {
  // remove previous active states
  const prevLeftRight = getLeftRight(prevMiddle);
  slides[prevMiddle].classList.remove('middle');
  slides[prevLeftRight.left].classList.remove('left');
  slides[prevLeftRight.right].classList.remove('right');
  // calculate new global index
  index = (direction === 'prev' ? index - 1 : index + 1);
  // calculate new middle, left, right
  prevMiddle = index % (slides.length - 0);
  const leftRight = getLeftRight(prevMiddle);

  console.log({
    index,
    left: leftRight.left,
    middle: prevMiddle,
    right: leftRight.right
  });

  slides[prevMiddle].classList.toggle('middle');
  slides[leftRight.left].classList.toggle('left');
  slides[leftRight.right].classList.toggle('right');
}

const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
const next = document.getElementById('next');

function onClick(e) {
  update(e.target.id);
}

prev.addEventListener('click', onClick);
next.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```css
#slides {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ec6161;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide>div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.middle {
  background: #75ec61;
}

.middle:after {
  content: 'MIDDLE';
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.left:after {
  content: 'LEFT';
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.right:after {
  content: 'RIGHT';
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#buttons {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
}

#prev,
#next {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
  <div class="slide">
    <div>0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <button id="prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add the length, before doing the modulo

You're almost there! You have recognized how to use the modulo function to wrap off the top end down to zero.

All you need to do to provide the opposite direction of wrapping round is to add the length, before doing the modulo.

Replace `index` with `(index + slides.length)`.

Now, instead of your modulo function (%) having to work only when you wrap round the high values, it is continuously in use even in a "normal" situation. Where you really do wrap round to high values, the modulo "works twice", as it were! It chops off two lots of slides.length.

Why this is good, is that when your index goes negative, the modulo function does nothing. Therefore the extra `slides.length` you have added, stays added, providing the wrap-around on the left that you wanted.

This is a common manoeuvre done for angles, for example, to get them into the canonical range 0-359.999999...

Check whether is a danger that the extent of the overshoot may be more than just a little, e.g. if you have a button to "Jump left by 10 positions", and your situation might have as few as 1 position displayed, then make sure to add 10 times `slides.length`. That way you will still avoid an error.

```js
// 5 slides
const slides = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

const slidesEl = document.getElementById('slides');
// populate slides[] with slides elements
for (let i = 0; i < slidesEl.children.length; i++) {
  slides[i] = slidesEl.children[i].children[0];
}

// global index
let index = 2;
// previous middle index, helps
// to clean up previous styles
let prevMiddle = index;

function getLeftRight(middle) {
  return {
    left: (middle - 1 + slides.length) % slides.length,
    right: (middle + 1) % slides.length,
  };
}

// set up initial active classes
const leftRight = getLeftRight(index);
slides[index].classList.add('middle');
slides[leftRight.left].classList.add('left');
slides[leftRight.right].classList.add('right');

function update(direction) {
  // remove previous active states
  const prevLeftRight = getLeftRight(prevMiddle);
  slides[prevMiddle].classList.remove('middle');
  slides[prevLeftRight.left].classList.remove('left');
  slides[prevLeftRight.right].classList.remove('right');
  // calculate new global index
  index = (direction === 'prev' ? index - 1 : index + 1);
  // calculate new middle, left, right
  prevMiddle = (index+slides.length) % (slides.length - 0);
  const leftRight = getLeftRight(prevMiddle);

  console.log({
    index,
    left: leftRight.left,
    middle: prevMiddle,
    right: leftRight.right
  });

  slides[prevMiddle].classList.toggle('middle');
  slides[leftRight.left].classList.toggle('left');
  slides[leftRight.right].classList.toggle('right');
}

const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
const next = document.getElementById('next');

function onClick(e) {
  update(e.target.id);
}

prev.addEventListener('click', onClick);
next.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```css
#slides {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ec6161;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide>div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.middle {
  background: #75ec61;
}

.middle:after {
  content: 'MIDDLE';
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.left:after {
  content: 'LEFT';
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.right:after {
  content: 'RIGHT';
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#buttons {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
}

#prev,
#next {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
  <div class="slide">
    <div>0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <button id="prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```